# pyodbc: i can't realize a query with condition where

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

i have this code:

```
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ = test_db.mdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

consulta = '''
            SELECT COL_NAME1, COL_NAME2, COL_NAME3, COL_NAME4
            FROM TABLENAME1
            WHERE ID = 1758 & PROCESS = "1587" & CATEGORY IN ('HDDS', 'HDD', 'SSD')
            '''
df = pd.read_sql(consulta, conn)
```

and when i run it i get this response (i deleted the query for privacy):

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
            SELECT  ...
            FROM ...
            WHERE ...'
: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] Error de sintaxis (falta operador) en la expresión de consulta ' ... '. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

the problem is after the first condition, because when i remove the second and third condition it works fine.

I suspect that the problem is because of the data type, but when I work the database from arcmap the query is written the same.

Comment: You want the word `AND` instead of `&`. The `&` is a bitwise and, which is not what you want here.

Comment: This isn't MySQL, the error says MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MSDN docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/string-functions-and-how-to-use-them-965efa84-7009-4603-9765-2eb4a099ec72), in MS Access SQL, the ampersand operator, `&`, is the concatenation operator to join two or more values together and is interchangeable with plus operator, `+`, for strings.

For logical expressions in `WHERE` clause, you want to use the `AND` operator to run the multiple conditions together. Also, consider using single quotes (though double quotes is allowable in MS Access) as best practice for general SQL.

```sql
WHERE ID = 1758 AND PROCESS = '1587' AND CATEGORY IN ('HDDS', 'HDD', 'SSD')
```